# What's the professional rule to create uppercase columns in maria db?

Tags: mariadb

I use Laravel and maria db.

I have to create a db with the following column_names:

```
d1
d2
d3
D1
D2
D3
```

Is there an official rule to create uppercase column names?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-case-sensitivity/ - `"while index, column, column aliases, stored routine and event names are never case sensitive."`

Comment: Even if it's technically possible, it doesn't make it a good idea. I wouldn't create multiple columns whoses name differ only in their cases...

Comment: But is there a rule how to handle it? I have ideas how to do it but I don't know if it's the right way (d1, d_1,....

Comment: you mean to ask if there is a convention for naming columns?

Comment: @obe yes right.

Comment: I am not aware of a single widely accepted convention but there may be (although I don't believe there would be something specific for MariaDB. If anything, then for MySQL, or SQL in general). Anyway, if there is, surely Google can find it. Just search for "SQL column naming conventions".